# Encrypting App.config / Web.config file

Tags: c#

I am abusing the Web.config file as the config file of some windows service exe files, because the service mostly needs the same settings as the IIS:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

if (File.Exists("..\\Web.config"))
{
    var path = Path.GetFullPath("..\\Web.config");
    logger.Info("Web.config gefunden in {0}", path);
    AppConfig.Change(path);
}
```

Someone else has tried to encrypt parts of the Web.config file:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe connectionStrings -app /ourapp
```

Renaming an original App.config to Web.config and back seems to be Microsoft's recommended way of encrypting an App.config file:

https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

However, the windows services won't start:

> Anwendung: MyService.exe
>   Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319
>   Beschreibung: Der Prozess wurde aufgrund einer unbehandelten Ausnahme beendet.
>   Ausnahmeinformationen: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

```
bei System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.ThrowBetterException(Boolean)  
bei System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.GetCryptoServiceProvider(Boolean, Boolean)  
bei System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.Decrypt(System.Xml.XmlNode)  
bei System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationSection.DecryptSection(System.String, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationProvider)  
bei System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.DecryptSection(System.String, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationSection)  
bei System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.DecryptSection(System.String, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationSection)  
bei System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CallHostDecryptSection(System.String, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationSection)  
bei System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CallHostDecryptSection(System.String, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationSection)  
bei System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.DecryptConfigSection(System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationProvider)
```

> Ausnahmeinformationen: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

```
bei System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(System.String[], System.Configuration.SectionInput, Boolean, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object)  
bei System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)  
bei System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)  
bei System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)  
bei System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)  
bei System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(System.String)  
bei System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String)  
bei System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)  
bei System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_ConnectionStrings()  
bei MyService.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Translation: _"The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception."_

Comment: the link you gave on encrypting passwords hasnt been applied - how is it relevant to the post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to grant permissions to access RSA container with which your section has been encrypted to the account under which your service runs. By default (with `aspnet_regiis` command you used in your question), that container is named "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey", so you need to do this:

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "YourServiceAccountHere"
```

Comment: I will try. Didn't think this could be the issue, since the ApplicationPool is running under Network Service, and the Service is running under NetworkService as well.

Comment: @Alexander ok let's see. I tried this on my machine and it works for me (that is - before running above command I have the same exception as you), but my pool and console application I tested with run under different accounts. Though I always thought you should give permissions like above even to application pool identity (so, that aspnet_regiis -pe doesn't do this automatically for you), but I may be wrong here.

Comment: Works. Could I somehow check the ACL of the container? Could it be that the access to the Web.config is running outside the Application Pool, under IUSR?

Comment: I checked the ACL of the key and found that by default, only `IIS_IUSRS`, `WMSVC`, `Administrators`, `SYSTEM` and `TrustedInstaller` have access. So the IIS seems to be reading the Machine key as `IIS_IUSRS`, not as `AppPoolIdentity`.